# Setup Docker Credential Helper for Docker Login with GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, github-actions

I have a project where I use GitHub Actions to build and push my image to the Docker registry. I use a shell script to do the Docker login and I get this message:

```
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in $HOME.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
```

So right now what I'm doing is to just delete the config.json after the build completes. The documentation says that I should use one of the credential store, but how should I go about doing it? Here is what I'm doing right now. Not sure if this is enough?

```
  echo "Attempting log in to $DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL"
  # Use Credential store to avoid unencrypted password showing un in $HOME/.docker/config.json
  echo '{ "credsStore": "pass" }' | tee "$HOME".docker/config.json
  echo "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME" --password-stdin
  echo "Successfully logged into Docker hub $DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL"
```

Comment: Could you share your workflow.yml file please? I would also suggest to use Docker Login Action: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/docker-login, I believe it could be useful in your context.

Comment: Is that Action only for Login? I mean after login, can I use the shell script to tag and push the images? I will give it a try perhaps!

Comment: It is only for login. You still need to perform your operation afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @GuiFalourd, I ended up using the [Docker Login GitHub](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/docker-login) action while retaining the rest of my interactions with Docker in my shell script.

Please note that the password should actually be a [personal access token](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/access-tokens/).

Here is the snippet:

```yaml
- name: docker-login
  uses: docker/login-action@v2
  with:
    username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
    password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}

- name: docker-push
  env:
    GH_REPO: github.com/${{ env.USER }}/${{ env.DEPLOYMENT_REPO_NAME }}
    API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.API_TOKEN }}
    DOCKER_APP_URL: ${{ env.DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL }}/${{ env.USER }}/plant-simulator
  run: |
    echo "Running sbt assembly for release version $RELEASE_VERSION"
    sbt "set test in assembly := {}" assembly
    bash docker/docker_push.sh && \
    bash ./.github/scripts/tag_deployment
```

Comment: The docker-login action produces identical behaviour to your original command, but just hides the warning.
https://github.com/docker/login-action/blob/21f251affc0769ccac8a1cf17e937592fb492337/src/docker.ts#L42